# Простая функция не выполняется

Tags: javascript, html

```js
var fon = 0;

function changefon(fon) {
  if (fon == 0)
    alert('не выводит alert');
}
```

```html
<a type="sumbit" href="#" onclick="changefon();" class="button_menu">Сменить фон</a>
```

Функция активируется по клику на кнопку. Пробовал и `var` и `let` и `const` - результат никакой.

Answer (score 2):

Параметр `fon` функции перекрывает одноименную переменную из внешнего лексического окружения функции.
И функция здесь вызывается без аргумента (см. в разметке) - а значит, при ее выполнении, локальная "переменная" `fon` (из параметров функции) содержит значение `undefined`. Это значение не равно числу `0`, то есть условие в операторе `if` не соблюдается, а поэтому и диалоговое окно алерта не появляется.

Чтобы в функции использовалась внешняя переменная, надо просто переименовать (или вообще убрать) параметр:

```js
var fon = 0;

function changefon(notFon) {
  if (fon == 0) {
    alert('теперь выводит alert');
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#dfd';
  }
}
```

```html
<a type="sumbit" href="#" onclick="changefon();" class="button_menu">Сменить фон</a>
```

Конечно же, это применимо и к `let`, и к `const` тоже. Именно перекрытие внешних переменных локальными - не зависит от способа их объявления (от способа объявления зависят другие вещи: поднятие переменных, область их видимости, время жизни, и изменяемость - более подробная информация о способах объявления есть в справочнике).

Comment: спасибо большое за подробное объяснение!